Embedded Service Deployment - Deployed From Sandbox to Sandbox - CORS Error
I'm naive to some of the newer Service Cloud settings, so I'm hoping someone can point me to the correct settings to review. I'm reaching out here before contacting Salesforce Support as you all are much more responsive than they are :)
I created an Embedded Service Deployment for "Messaging for In-App and Web" in one of my sandboxes and deployed it to another of my sandboxes (both sandboxes have Service Cloud and Omni-channel enabled). When I click the "Test Messaging" button (Description: Test your custom messaging experience in a Visualforce page.) in the Embedded Service Deployment Settings page, the chat/messaging widget does not load in the subsequent VF page. I see this error in the console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://{{}}--targetSandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce-scrt.com/embeddedservice/v1/embedded-service-config?orgId=abc&esConfigName=Testing&language=en_US' from origin 'https://{{}}--targetSandbox--c.sandbox.vf.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Which is accurate - Note in the below screenshot, the Access-Control-Allow headers are not present in the request to https://{{}}--targetSandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce-scrt.com/embeddedservice/v1/embedded-service-config?orgId=abc&esConfigName=Testing&language=en_US

I then create a new Embedded Service Deployment from scratch in the sandbox following the same procedure as I did in the original sandbox (with a slightly different name), Publish it, and use the "Test Messaging" button as before. Everything works as expected. As we can see in the below screenshot, the Access-Control-Allow headers are present:

Has anyone successfully deployed an Embedded Service Deployment from one sandbox to another? If so, what metadata components did you include? Any idea where, if at all, I can control the CORS for this Embedded Service Deployment?
Thanks for any advice!

It turns out that only domains that start with https:// will be included in the CORS header. In order to fix this, you need to go to Sites, select the site that corresponds with your Embedded Service Deploy, and update the Trusted Domains to include https://


